# A bounded function on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> How to prove that the function $f(x,y)=\displaystyle\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$ if $(0,0)\not = (0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=0$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I like some advice to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $AM-GM$ inequality $ \frac{a + b }{2} \geq \sqrt{ab} $ with $a = x^2 $ and $b = y^4$ which are obviously positive :

$$ \frac{ x^2 + y^4}{2} \geq xy^2 \implies \frac{1}{x^2+y^4}\leq \frac{1}{2xy^2}$$

Hence,

$$ f(x,y) \leq \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: That is a very simple solution! Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo in the first inequality involving $(x,y)$ and you're missing absolute values throughout.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** define $r,\theta$ such as
\begin{align}
y^2 &= r\sin\theta\\x &= r\cos\theta
\end{align}

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your "hint" ? thanks

Comment: @PedroArbizu using trig identities this becomes $\sin\theta\cos\theta$ which is bounded.